grayed out file in vscode

I right-clicked this file then by accident clicked something. Ever since, this file is gray.
I don't know what that means, what it does, how it happened or how to make it go back to normal. AI also doesn't know.
Ctrl+shift+f the file name finds nothing. It isn't on any .gitignore.
How to get it back to normal?
These missclicks happen due to a bad touchpad. I just misclicked again, and now it isn't gray anymore.
I would love to understand what causes this.

Context menu after this magically fixed itself:


Installed extentions:

and python, and python debugger.

I don't think there's anything in the context menu that ignores files by default. Show a screenshot of your context menu.

@Destroy666 It isn't ignoring, as it isn't in gitignore

So I assume you reviewed the whole code and you are certain VSCode only ignores files in .gitignore? Anyways, voting to close now, since you haven't answered a basic question and this is currently unanswerable IMO.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654164/why-is-my-node-modules-folder-greyed-out-after-command-npm-install and also https://usercomp.com/news/1399137/fix-grayed-out-file-in-vs-code Have you done a web search regarding this and explored the main reasons suggested in the results?

@Destroy666 I am not logged in 100% of the time to stackexchange, give me some time before you close please... I edited the question now with the context menu.

@music2myear Yes and I also said it in the original questions. You have links but said nothing about what's in them that I missed. What have I missed?

You answered partially so you were logged in. Anyways, the context menu looks fine. Are you sure it's after you click context menu? What extensions are you using?

@Destroy666 yes, sure. Updated again

I would say that you have deleted it.  So, recover it from a backup or from wherever you copied from originally.
If its a published website then you could copy the from there.
